# Build Android XMPP instant messenger and server Example

Tags: android, server, xmpp, instant-messaging

**Backgrounds**

I want to learn about instant messenger, both android app and server.

In my first thought, I want to use GCM to communicate. But I found the article below. By this article, GCM is not good for sending messages, and It seems that I need to build dedicated messenger server.

[Instant Messaging on Android with Google Cloud Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368280/instant-messaging-on-android-with-google-cloud-messaging)

So I googled how to build instant messenger server. As a result, I found that XMPP is popular technology. But I couldn't found examples.

Finally I found source below. This example seems that includes both android and server side source, but I'm not sure this example using XMPP.

https://code.google.com/p/simple-android-instant-messaging-application/

**Q1:** Is there a good example source of XMPP Server?

**Q2:** Does anybody have experience about https://code.google.com/p/simple-android-instant-messaging-application/ ? Is this a example is good for beginner?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below results.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/

http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample

http://javapapers.com/android/android-chat-with-google-gcm-xmpp/

Comment: Thanks! I will try this.